# How to integrate $\int \frac{v}{g-kv}dv$

Tags: integration

How to integrate $$\int \frac{v}{g-kv}\,\mathrm dv$$ it's supposed to be equal to $$ -\frac{v}{k} -\frac{g}{k^2}\ln(g-kv)$$ but I can't get that, I tried a substitution $u=g-kv$ and got close but no right? Any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the integral $$I=\int \frac{v}{g-k\,v}dv$$ several things could be done (Mann gave you one). Another solution is a change of variable (as you obviously tried) : set $g-k\,v=x$ that is to say $v=\frac{g-x}{k}$, $dv=-\frac{dx}{k}$. Replacing, we then have $$I=-\int\frac{g-x}{k^2\, x}dx=-\frac{g}{k^2}\int \frac{dx}x+\frac{1}{k^2}\int dx=-\frac{g}{k^2}\,\log(x)+\frac{x}{k^2}+C$$ If you need, go back from $x$ to $v$ and get $$I=-\frac{g }{k^2}\,\log (g-k\, v)-\frac{v}{k}+C$$

Answer (score 6):

Write $$\int \frac{v}{g-kv}dv$$ as

$$\frac{1}{-k}\int \frac{g-kv-g}{g-kv}dv$$

$$\frac{1}{-k}\left[\int \left(\frac{1}{1}\right)- \left(\frac{g}{g-kv}\right)dv\right]$$

$$\frac{1}{-k}\int \left(\frac{1}{1}\right)dv- \frac{1}{-k}\int \left(\frac{g}{g-kv}\right)dv$$

Comment: just wanted to write the same thing, then you made your edit :D

Comment: Haha :D, I know the feels.